# Dropdown Div Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code does not drop down and up the div when clicked,It doesn't perform anything.But Im trying the exact code that works here http://jsfiddle.net/vNeXq/

```
<html>
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
        $('#login').click(function(){
    $('#loginForm').slideToggle('fast');
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loginWrapper">
        <a id="login">Login</a>
        <div id="loginForm">
            <form name="login" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS File

```
    #loginWrapper
    {
        width:400px;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
    }
    #login 
    {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #loginForm 
    {
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your project?

Comment: I guess having the codes between <script></script> does that

Comment: No, you have to include jQuery and then include you script files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you haven't included jQuery. The jQuery library is necessary for the script you want to run. You can download a copy of jQuery from [here](https://jquery.com/download/) or you can use a copy [hosted from Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery). jQuery has to be included before the code you want to run.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loginWrapper">
        <a id="login">Login</a>
        <div id="loginForm">
            <form name="login" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- INCLUDE JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#login').click(function(){
              $('#loginForm').slideToggle('fast');
          });
      }):

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it looks like Im new to Javascript.I didnt include jQuery  and $(document).ready(function(){} at first.Thanks so much.Now it works

Answer (score 0):

If you have included jQuery in your project you maybe want to wrap your code with a function that executes when the page is loaded, so you are sure everything is there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#login').click(function(){
        $('#loginForm').slideToggle('fast');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like:

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $(document).on('click','#login',function(){
                    $('#loginForm').slideToggle('fast');
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that are your not including the jQuery library in the head of the html file.

Include the jquery library (it should be before your script):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In order for jQuery to modify the html document it must wait until the page is ready. You can do this by putting your function into:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     // your code here
});
```

So your script will end up looking like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#login').click(function(){
        $('#loginForm').slideToggle('fast');
      });
});
```